# Is there a way to put a breakpoint when my active window changes?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Is there a way to put a breakpoint on `ActiveWindow.change` ? I have a macro that I run in a new, unsaved Excel file, that is supposed to open CSV file, save it as, process it, and keep it in focus. Instead of that, when the macro is done it selects the empty new file that was unsaved, and puts the CSV in the background. This happens even though I use the code below, just before `End Sub`:

```
WKB1.Activate
WKB1.Sheets(1).Activate
WKB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
```

The thing is the three rows of code above do set the focus correctly, but at end sub it switches back to the unsaved file.

I was thinking that if I can set a breakpoint whenever the active window name changes, I can catch when that happens, because the macro I'm working with is huge, and I can't find the bug manually.

Kind regards,
Daniel

Comment: Don't activate, don't select. Fully qualify your references instead

Comment: Can you give me an example of what would mean to fully qualify references?

Comment: Would be much better to show the code you're having a problem with, rather than us guessing the best approach to fix your problem...

Comment: Your third line is fully qualified, that is it specifies the workbook, worksheet and cell you want to affect. If I write
WKB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = 34
 it will put 34 into that cell on that sheet on that workbook irrespective of what workbook or sheet is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was quite stupid, but I fixed the issue by creating a new ribbon tab and run the macro from the ribbon instead of running it from VBA. Also i removed and Activate o Select commands. The macro was behaving the same, even after i removed the Activate and Select commands, the thing that fixed it was running it from a new menu.